# how to set multiply tcp ports in azur VM?

Tags: azure, acl

I want to have a set of ports range (1001-1020, 80-90).
I tried but could do all range only add every port manual by itself: 1001,1002,1003 etc.
How do I set it as a range?

Question # 2
How do I save a list of tcp / http / rdp to be auto loaded when a new VM is used? 
AWS has a function when loading a new image to use a specific basket of internet rules. I didn't find a way to do this in azure. can that be done in azure as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you would typically do with PowerShell. Here's an example that reads the endpoints from a CSV file and adds it to a VM:

```
$endpoints = Import-Csv $csvFile -header Name,Protocol,PublicPort,LocalPort -delimiter ';' | foreach {
    New-Object PSObject -prop @{
        Name = $_.Name;
        Protocol = $_.Protocol;
        PublicPort = [int32]$_.PublicPort;
        LocalPort = [int32]$_.LocalPort;
    }
}

# Add each endpoint.
Foreach ($endpoint in $endpoints)
{
     Add-AzureEndpoint -VM $vm -Name $endpoint.Name -Protocol $endpoint.Protocol.ToLower() -PublicPort $endpoint.PublicPort -LocalPort $endpoint.LocalPort
}
```

More information is available here: http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/adding-multiple-endpoints-to-your-windows-azure-virtual-machines-by-using-a-csv-file/

Comment: thanks. i am not a programmer and amazon aws is much more easier to use... why don't azure have simple videos with step by step instructions or like your blog?? also, how do i connect the image with that csv import script so any time i run a VM with that image it will load the same csv file?